# iPhone turns itself off with lots of charge left

Tags: iphone

My iPhone turns itself off when it has a lot of battery charge left, sometimes when it's still at 70%. Then I can't turn it on at all unless I plug it in to a charger.... After I do that, the apple logo appears and it turns on as normal with lots of charge.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What model is your iPhone? I had an iPhone 5 with faulty battery doing the same; Apple replaced those for free.

Comment: It is a 3G so quite old but has just started doing it.

Comment: Maybe you should think about replacing the battery.

Comment: Ok.  Maybe that is the issue.  But it holds charge?  I don't know. Maybe I should go see an apple retailer...

Answer (score 4):

It appears your battery is faulty.

If you have an iPhone 5, check the [iPhone 5 Battery Replacement Program](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-battery/other_countries.html) to get a free replacement.

If you have an iPhone 6s, check the [iPhone 6s Program for Unexpected Shutdown issues](https://support.apple.com/iphone6s-unexpectedshutdown) to get a free replacement.

If your phone is under warranty or AppleCare extended warranty, you may be eligible for a free battery replacement. Even if it is not under warranty, go to the [Apple Support webpage](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/repair/battery-power/), "Start a service request" and fill in your problem details so Apple can help you.

If you have a Mac, you can find information about your battery by plugging into your computer and installing the free [CoconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) app to check its health.

[image: CoconutBattery showing iPhone 5]