# iPhone 8 randomly turns off and on, 100% to 0% back to 100% in a minute

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, charging

I have a iPhone 8, iOS 13.3, and today it's been turning off and on randomly. I've seen posts about this, but none with my exact problem - it seems to be in two modes:

Mode 1: doesn't charge at all no matter what, or at least, indicate that it's charging

Mode 2: charges normally

The thing is, I could switch from one mode to another by just forcing a restart, and when that happens, the charging I did in Mode 1 is shown on Mode 2....and then it restarts back in Mode 1 again after some use. I can go from 100% to 0% back to 100% in just a minute by just restarting (unplugged), which is super perplexing.

I'm guessing it's a software issue, but I've been living in a really humid area for awhile so I'm not sure. Any idea what's happening? Thanks!

Comment: See this OP for similar question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192978/iphone-turns-itself-off-with-lots-of-charge-left